# Emulate Power Point Transitions with Reveal.JS - Custom Slide In/Out

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, reveal.js

I am using Reveal.JS to create some slides, I have built a sample of what I want to create in PowerPoint and now trying to figure out how to either use CSS animations on elements or have custom `data-transitions` for slide in and slide out.

This video shows the power point presentation slide in/out effect and how far I have gotten with the CSS implementation.

My question could be answered with two different solutions.

1. CSS that could easily be applied on slide in or slide out that would create these power point effects.
2. Plugin or modification to Reveal.js that would allow me to handle in / out transitions.

**Goal**

[Video Example](http://youtu.be/3PfYuJ9lXFs?hd=1)

**HTML**

```
<div class="reveal">

  <div class="slides">

    <section data-state='gq black' data-transition='none'>
      <div data-animate="fadeInGq" data-duration="5">
        <h1>Wooden
          <br/>Bowie</h1>
        <br />
        <h2>Hollywood Collection</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Black Slides
----------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

.gq.black body {
  background: url('./line-vertical-white-100.svg'),  url('./circle-white-100.svg'), black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom -10px left 50px, top -110px right -290px;
  background-size: auto 82%, auto auto;
}
.gq.black .slides section {
  top: 100px !important;
}

.gq.black .reveal h1 {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 2.77em;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
.gq.black .reveal h2 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
.gq.black.fade-in .reveal h2 {
  color: red;
}

/* 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
White Slides
----------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

.gq.white body {
  background: url('./line-horizontal-black-100.svg'),  url('./circle-black-100.svg'), white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom 30px left, bottom -180px right -290px;
  background-size: 45% auto, auto auto;
}

.gq.white .reveal h1 {
  margin-right: 500px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: none;
  color: black;
}


.gq .reveal h2 {
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.gq.white .reveal h2 {
  margin-right: 500px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 100;
}

/* 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Slide In Transition
----------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInGq {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-8%, 18%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-8%, 18%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInGq {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-8%, 18%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-8%, 18%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.fadeInGq {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInGq;
  animation-name: fadeInGq;
}
```

Comment: please provide jsbin link with problem. It will be easy to implement custom CSS animation. Also as I know there is no plugin with such animation and fast way is to implement custom CSS animation and after that pack it as a plugin for reveal.js